# crypotjs - Decrypting value with findOne()

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, mongoose, cryptojs

I've encrypted a URL value and stored it in MongoDB. What I don't understand is how would findOne would find the URL if it's encrypted. I don't think I can just encrypt again with generatedUrl and the values will match.  Maybe there's a better way than crypto?

Encrypting here

```
app.post("/api/users/passwordurl", function(req, res) {

  crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {});

  let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

  let hash = crypto
    .createHash("sha256")
    .update(req.body.url)
    .digest("hex");

  let secret_message = req.body.url;
  let key = "12345678123456781234567812345678";

  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(secret_message, "utf-8", "hex");
  encrypted += cipher.final("hex");
  console.log("encrypted: " + encrypted);



  const url = new Url({
    url: encrypted,
    used: false
  });

  //saves to database with mongoose
  url.save().then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "URL success",
      postId: result._id
    });
  });
});
```

Need to decrypt here

```
app.get("/resetpassword/:id/:token", function(req, res) {


  User.findById(req.params.id).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Auth failed"
      });
    }

    var secret = user.password + "-" + user.passwordCreated.getTime();
    var payload = jwt.decode(req.params.token, secret);

    console.log("USER FOUND: ", user);

    let generatedUrl = `http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/${payload.id}/${req.params.token}`;

    Url.findOne({ url: generatedUrl }).then(url => {

      if (!url) {
        res.send("link has expired");
        res.end();
      } else {
        res.send(
          '<form action="/resetpassword" method="POST">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' +
            payload.id +
            '" />' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' +
            req.params.token +
            '" />' +
            '<input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your new password..." />' +
            '<input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />' +
            "</form>"
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you encrypting the URL at all?

Comment: It's a one-time URL for pw reset. Once you reset the pw, the link is no longer valid. If  anyone got their hands on it, they could use it. So encrypting it would help make it fool-proof I feel. I was also going to add a 5 min TTL on url in mongodb. Maybe encrypting is overkill?

Comment: *shrug* You're already going to send it via email; encrypting will do nothing there. If they're in your DB you're screwed anyway. I don't really see the point since it'll be sent in email.

Comment: Ok. I'll hold off with doing this for now. Thanks for your input